# How to get the current plugin name?

Tags: plugins, directory

I need to get the current plugin name using a define like this

```
define(PLUGIN_NAME, plugin_basename(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

Regrettably, that code doesn't work because the php file is nested inside a subdirectory (includes) of my plugin directory and it returns

```
my-plugin/includes
```

Is there any function from Wordpress API to accomplish this task?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `define(PLUGIN_NAME, "MY PLUGIN NAME");` is enough. Why do you need something dynamically that's not dynamic at all.

Comment: because I suppose that the user might install the plugin into a directory of his choice.

Comment: Plugins can only be installed in the mu folder or plugins folder and cannot go into sub directories, so you don't have any thing to worry about.

Comment: I mean that the user might install the plugin into plugins/theplugins rather than plugins/myplugin

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Reread my previous comment.

Comment: If a user intentionally add a plugin into an incorrect folder, it is his own problem. That should not be your problem.

Comment: You should put the define in your main plugin file `myplugin/myplugin.php`

Answer (score 11):

Within the plugin's main PHP file:

```
$plugin_data = get_plugin_data( __FILE__ );
$plugin_name = $plugin_data['Name'];
```

Comment: This only works in admin, by the way

Comment: I like this, but when I output all the associative array keys & values, only the TextDomain gives a value: `PluginURI = 
Version = 
Description = 
Author = 
AuthorURI = 
TextDomain = my-calculator
DomainPath = 
Network = 
Title = 
AuthorName =  `

... how do I set/retrieve all the other values for #plugin_data ?

Comment: Make sure that the main comment in your plugin file contains the relevant data as per https://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header

Answer (score 2):

you can get plugin name in a subdirectory of your plugin by this snippet code:

```
$plugin = basename( plugin_dir_path(  dirname( __FILE__ , 2 ) ) );
```

only you should write level of subdirectory relative to plugin folder in second parameter of dirname() function.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the plugin folder name regardless of where the file is located and not having to know anything about the directory structure of the plugin.

```
$plugin_folder_name = reset(explode('/', str_replace(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/', '', __DIR__)));
```

For a break down of what is happening

```
// Get the relative path to current file from plugin root
$file_path_from_plugin_root = str_replace(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/', '', __DIR__);

// Explode the path into an array
$path_array = explode('/', $file_path_from_plugin_root);

// Plugin folder is the first element
$plugin_folder_name = reset($path_array);
```

Comment: The single line causes a notice to be thrown "Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference" so I use the long way round version.